# What is the best way to simulate a robotic arm?

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, matlab, simulation

I have been working on a senior design project. In this project, we designed a 4-DOF robot arm. Now, I want to do a simulation for this system. I guess I have to design controllers for the servo motors. And, combine those with my simulator. What are your thoughts about this? How should I do the simulation? What programs, tools,  or frameworks should I use? I have been thinking to use MATLAB Simscape and SimMechanics for simulation and Simulink for the design of the controller. Also, one other option for the simulation is the MoveIt framework.

Thanks for your opinions.

Comment: Is the arm completely designed already? And you just want dynamics? You’re asking too many different things and it seems like you, yourself don’t have any specific ideas what needs to be done. Pick a single question for us to answer, after that you can ask a new single specific question

Answer (score 1):

The Simulink and SimMechanics combination is a well suited one. You can add further SimScape elements for motors ot similar elements are needed. There is a Matlab demo on simiar topics [here](https://mathworks.com/help/physmod/sm/examples/3-roll-robotic-wrist-mechanism.html) and [here](https://mathworks.com/help/physmod/sm/examples/stewart-platform.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Gazebo. 
http://gazebosim.org/
It has an interface to ROS which makes development of control software easy. and note that ROS is only usable on LINUX.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use V-REP, it is very straighforward to use and got a MATLAB and ROS interface. Is usable in WIndows, MAC and Linux.